# How to replace a queue in RabbitMQ without losing or duplicating events in production

Tags: rabbitmq

Assume we have a queue A bound to an exchange E. Now we want to replace the queue with a queue B or perhaps even with two queues B and C that use different binding keys. For simplicity, we take the simpler case where we just want to replace A with B.

Is there a way to achieve this without losing or duplicating events?
For instance, can we somehow issue a binding change transaction that removes the binding to queue A and adds the binding for queue B in an atomic step?

I'm assuming a continuous stream of incoming messages. If the producer keeps producing while I add a new queue and then unbind the old one I assume, I would run the risk that events that come in between the adding of the new binding and removing of the old are duplicated. The other way around, removing the binding for the old queue, then adding the binding for the new one, I would assume I risk loosing the messages that come in in-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Loosing or duplicating events" seems to be related to how your subscribers are implemented and not RabbitMQ.

For example, if you stop consuming messages, then move your messages to a different queue (in order), and only then restart your subscriber on the new queue, you will not loose messages.

You can also simply let the "old" subscribers consume the "A" queue until there are no messages in it, while "new" subscribers only consume from queue "B", to finally decommission the old queues and subscribers.

> Can we somehow issue a binding change transaction that removes the binding to queue A and adds the binding for queue B in an atomic step?

**No.**

From the [RrabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html), in the table:

> Transactional exchange/queue/binding creation/deletion:   **NO**

It gets complicated if you can't stop the producers while you swap consumers. If it's really impossible and your definitely MUST keep the order, you could introduce an additional buffer queue and perhaps use the shovel plugin to consume from it. Orchestrating such change would involve stopping the shovel first, so the A queue can be completely consumed.

I would only do this if it's a one-off,but  I wouldn't want this to be part of say, my deploy pipeline. Without having all the context, it would seem that you risk re-implementing Kafka here.

Comment: I'm assuming a continuous stream of incoming messages. The consumer indeed should not be problematic, but if the producer keeps producing while I add a new queue and then unbind the old one wouldn't I run the risk that events that come in between the adding of the new binding and removing of the old be duplicated?

Comment: @FredWoozley I clarified that such atomic operation is not supported.

Comment: I feared as much, but didn't see the crucial bit in the documentation. It's definitely for a one-off. Will take a look at the buffer queue and wait a day for others to chime in before accepting an answer. Thanks already!